# Error when adding this code symfony

Tags: symfony

I get this

> [2/2] Twig_Error_Runtime: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Controller "PagesBundle:pages:menu" for URI
>   "/_fragment" is not callable.").   +

when i add :

```
{% render(controller("PagesBundle:pages:menu")) %}
```

in my Layout.html.twig

i am using symfony 2.4.10 and netbeans 8

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the the `P` uppercase of `Pages`.

```
   {% render(controller("PagesBundle:Pages:menu")) %}
```

Where `PagesBundle` is the name of the Bundle (if it is under a App Directory, it would be `AppPagesBundle`, `Pages` correspond to your Controller `Controller/PagesController` and `menu` to your Action named `menuAction`

Comment: Well to be honest i am following someone else's code and that code worked for him i am 100% xertain that i followed him correctly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to render template instead of the controller action/method!

here is the format

```
{{ render(controller('BundleName:ControllerName:ActionName')) }}
```

read doc here [How to Embed Controllers in a Template](https://symfony.com/doc/master/templating/embedding_controllers.html)